# SLF4J log4j NoSuchMethodError on Category

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback

I'm using SLF4J + LogBack to handle my logging, and have the appropriate jars to route the other logging framework calls. However I've run across the issue noted here:
http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j

Where in I'm getting a `NoSuchMethodError` on the call of an `Appender` (specifically `Category.getRoot()`).

It mentions that using a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file should fix these issues, but I'm not exactly sure what that config file would look like (which appenders and categories to use), or where to place it (same location as the logback.xml?)

I've also seen this:
[Issues replacing Log4j with LogBack, log4j-over-slf4j.jar shortcomings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028703/issues-replacing-log4j-with-logback-log4j-over-slf4j-jar-shortcomings)

Which seems to be essentially the same question, but never really answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log4j's `Appender` and `Category` classes contain some methods (for example `Category.addAppender()`) which can change the logging configuration. Since slf4j just a simple facade for logging, the configuration fully depends on the underlying logging framework (logback, log4j, java-util-logging etc.), so slf4j does not support these methods.

Check the [source code of the `Category` class of the log4j-over-slf4j module](https://github.com/ceki/slf4j/blob/master/log4j-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/Category.java), there is no `getRoot()` method. I don't think that any property or xml file would change it. From http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j:

> However, when log4j is configured through a configuration file, be it log4j.properties or log4j.xml, the log4j-over-slf4j module should just work fine.

It just means that if your application's logging is configured only with `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` the `log4j-over-slf4j` module will work fine because the application does not use the configuration methods of the `Appender` and Category (and maybe other) classes. It uses log4j just for logging, not to configure it and the required logger methods exist in the log4j-over-slf4j module. So, if your application uses the configuration methods you have to modify the code.

Comment: So what you're saying is, my reading comprehension skills need to be a little better. ;-)

Comment: No, I'm not :-) It was a really good question. SLF4J doc should be improved, it's confusing now.